# How to keep EXIF of an edited image?

Tags: c#, wpf, jpeg, exif

So my program is fixing some image artefacts, it goes like this:

```
void FixFile(string path)
{
    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(new BitmapImage(new Uri(path)));
    bmp.Lock();

    // magick

    bmp.Unlock();

    using (var stream = new FileStream(path.Replace("DSC", "fix_DSC"), FileMode.Create))
    {
        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

The problem is that fixed image contains no EXIF data. How do I transfer EXIF data from the original image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the source bitmap as `BitmapFrame`, not `BitmapImage`. Then pass the `Metadata` property of the source to the new `BitmapFrame` that is added to the `Frames` collection of the encoder.

```
public void FixFile(string path)
{
    var source = BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(path));
    var metadata = (BitmapMetadata)source.Metadata;

    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(source);
    bmp.Lock();
    // magick
    bmp.Unlock();

    var target = BitmapFrame.Create(bmp, null, metadata, null); // here

    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(target);

    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(path.Replace("DSC", "fix_DSC")))
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works great. There was a problem with tags ExifImageWidth and ExifImageHeight stored as UInt16 instead of UInt32, but I've handled it.